# Data não "respeita" formatação com PHP

Tags: php, data, timestamp

Eu dei uma procurada e não encontrei solução pro problema, eu realmente acho que deve ser algo simples que talvez eu esteja errando.

No sistema os usuários podem inserir alguns arquivos via intranet, quando eles insere o arquivo eles informam o tempo que esse arquivo vai ficar disponivel, essa data é salva como int basicamente quando o cara clica em enviar no codigo acontece o seguinte: `strtotime(date('d/m/Y H:i:s'))`  que pega a data atual, até aí tudo ok.

Eu acredito que o `strotime` não está convertendo a data para um `int` que corresponde a data atual.

Aí eu preciso recuperar esses dados em determinada pagina para verificar se ele ainda está disponivel, a data vem no formato `int` e eu converto para uma data humana mais precisamente setada com `date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');` essa linha fica no arquivo de configuração que é chamado em todos os arquivos do sistema.

Aí quando eu vou pegar as datas tudo responde normalmente, mas quando eu vou pegar a data atual novamente, ele substitui o mês pelo dia, mesmo com a data formatada:

```
$dataatual   = strtotime(date('d/m/Y H:i:s'));
echo $comparador1 = date('d/m/Y H:i:s',$dataatual);
```

O resultado que vem é o`03/12/2019 10:36:32`.

O resto do codigo funciona normalmente, o erro é na linha que eu pego a data atual que está em código aqui acima, não estou entendendo oque está acontecendo.

Então eu pego a data que vem do banco tambem como int e a conversão ocorre normamente.

1. tempo corresponde ao int que vem do banco de dados
2. tempoV corresponde a uma variavel que vem com um valor para fazer alteração na data ex: `+1 hour`

   ```
   $datacriado  = strtotime(date('d/m/Y H:i:s', $x['tempo']));
   echo '< br>';
   echo $comparador2 = date('d/m/Y H:i:s',$datacriado);
   $comparador2 = strtotime(date('d/m/Y H:i:s',$datacriado).$x['tempoV']);
   ```

Comment: Acredito que seja porque você está fazendo o date('d/m/Y H:i:s') duas vezes, ai na primeira ele troca o mês pelo dia ficando no formato correto, 12/03/2019 e na segunda vez que você faz ele inverte denovo ficando 03/12/2019

Comment: No seu último código, faça apenas `$datacriado = $x['tempo']`. Não tem porque transformar o tempo em string para depois obter o número novamente...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema está na primeira linha (`strtotime(date('d/m/Y H:i:s'));`).

[Segundo a documentação de `strtotime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php#refsect1-function.strtotime-notes):

> Dates in the m/d/y or d-m-y formats are disambiguated by looking at the separator between the various components: **if the separator is a slash (/), then the American m/d/y is assumed**

Ou seja, se a data estiver separada por barras, assume-se que o formato é mês/dia/ano. Exemplo:

```
echo strtotime('12/03/2019 10:52:04'); // 1575377524
echo strtotime('03/12/2019 10:52:04'); // 1552398724
```

A primeira linha retorna 1575377524, que corresponde a [3 de dezembro](https://www.epochconverter.com/timezones?q=1575377524&tz=UTC). A segunda linha retorna 1552398724, que corresponde a [12 de março](https://www.epochconverter.com/timezones?q=1552398724&tz=UTC).

Então bastaria inverter o dia e mês no seu formato:

```
strtotime(date('m/d/Y H:i:s'))
```

Mas na verdade tudo isso é desnecessário (converter para string só para obter o timestamp em seguida). Se quer o timestamp correspondente ao instante atual, basta usar a função [`time()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.time.php):

```
$dataatual = time(); // valor do timestamp atual
```

---

Existe ainda um outro detalhe a se atentar no seu código, quando o dia for maior que 12:

```
// 23 de dezembro
$x = strtotime('23/12/2019 10:52:04');
var_dump($x); // bool(false)
```

Eu tentei passar "23 de dezembro", mas já vimos que `strtotime` tentará interpretar como "dia 12 do mês 23". Só que em vez de dar erro (já que mês 23 não existe), o retorno é um boolean (`false`).

Só que se passarmos esse valor (`false`) de volta para `date`, ele é interpretado como o número zero:

```
echo date('d/m/Y H:i:s', $x);
// é o mesmo que
echo date('d/m/Y H:i:s', 0);
```

Ambos produzem a data equivalente ao instante zero, que é o próprio [*Unix Epoch*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) (1 de janeiro de 1970, meia-noite, em [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time)). No caso, o *Unix Epoch* é convertido para o timezone *default*, por isso no meu caso a saída foi `31/12/1969 21:00:00`.

Por isso, para obter o timestamp atual é melhor usar simplesmente `time()` (mais direto e sem precisar fazer conversões de/para string). Se precisar de outras datas que não a atual, basta trocar o dia e mês no seu formato.

---

#### Sobre o seu código

```
$datacriado = strtotime(date('d/m/Y H:i:s', $x['tempo']));
```

Se `$x['tempo']` é o valor numérico do timestamp, todo esse processo é desnecessário. `date` vai pegar esse valor e transformar em uma string. Em seguida, `strtotime` pega a string e transforma de volta no valor numérico do timestamp. Por que não fazer simplesmente:

```
$datacriado = $x['tempo'];
```

De qualquer forma, vamos mostrar que o código continua errado:

```
$tempo = 1552398724;
echo date('d/m/Y H:i:s', $tempo); // 12/03/2019 10:52:04

$datacriado = strtotime(date('d/m/Y H:i:s', $tempo));
echo $datacriado; // 1575377524

echo date('d/m/Y H:i:s', $datacriado); // 03/12/2019 10:52:04
```

Novamente, veja que `strtotime` interpretou o dia como o mês e vice-versa, gerando um timestamp diferente do original. O problema está no formato da string que é passada para `strtotime`.

Comment: mas tem um motivo de porque isso acontece só com essa data? as outras datas recebem o mesmo tratamento e vem no formato esperado, eu não sei se eu posso colar o codigo aqui então vou dar uma atualizada no post só pra você entender, mas a sua resposta já funcionou thanks

Comment: @MartinsLuan Tem certeza que todas as outras estão funcionando? Se vc passar `d/m/y` para `strtotime`, ele irá interpretar como `m/d/y`. Talvez as datas que funcionam estejam usando outras coisas (outro formato, etc), ou todas estão com erro mesmo.. Enfim, atualizei a resposta

Comment: Paramentemente funciona sim, o resultado do ultimo código é esse: 12/03/2019 11:06:31
12/03/2019 11:06:31, sobre o formato das datas d/m/Y não seria day/month/yers ? no caso eu converti apenas pra ver se as datas estavam no tempo correto, pq com o strotime eu não consigo saber sem converter

Comment: Com o código que está na pergunta eu não consigo simular o caso que "funciona". Mas enfim, eu acho essas funções de datas do PHP meio confusas, principalmente por causa desses comportamentos arbitrários ("se o separador for barra, então é m/d/y", etc), então eu sugiro usar o código da resposta mesmo :-)